# Как добавить free space к основному диску на mac?

Tags: консоль, macos, ssd, диск

У меня 2 ТБ памяти на маке, но 499 из них - свободное пространство, которое нельзя распределить, дисковая утилита выглядит следующим образом:

[image: Дисковая утилита]

Скажу сразу, что к этой ситуации я привёл себя сам, пока искал как объединить два раздела.
В процессе поиска я нашёл команду, которая удалила один из моих разделов
Команда вроде была

```sh
sudo diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk0s2
```

и теперь мой список разделов, контейнеров и прочего хлама выглядит следующим образом:

[image: diskutil list]

Может кто-то сталкивался с таким и знает как объединить free space основным разделом без переустановки macOS, или на крайний случай сделать это пространство отдельным разделом.

Comment: а вам bootcamp всё ещё нужен?

Comment: Да, bootcamp используется, но если есть решение посредством его сноса, то рассмотрю и переустановлю его позже

Comment: попробуйте для начала запустить первую помощь, но мне кажется проблема в том, что пустой раздел сейчас находится за bootcamp, поэтому и недоступен

Comment: Первую помощь уже запускал, не помогло

Comment: а до этого эти 500 гигабайт были в разделе для windows? форматирование NTFS?

Comment: Нет, они были отдельным разделом (не томом) ещё до того как я поднял bootcamp.
Формат был APFS

Comment: Герман, как вы решили эту проблему, у меня такая же ситуация(

Comment: По итогу решил переустановить macOS, иначе не вышло